# VLOOKUP to the left from another sheet in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup, importrange

I have a spreadsheet that is managed externally to my own spreadsheet in Google Sheets.  I am trying to pull in data to my sheet from that external sheet so I have a centralized location to display task items that pertain to me.  Here is the formula that I thought would work:

```
=VLOOKUP("My Name", IMPORTRANGE("https://linkto.othersheet.com", {"Tab1!$G$1:$G$999","Tab2!$A$1:$A$999"}),2,FALSE)
```

The formula should use `IMPORTRANGE` to pull in 2 of the columns (or multiple columns) from the external sheet.  Then do a `VLOOKUP` based on "My Name", find any matches in column G and reply with the value in the corresponding column A.

If I set the index to 1, it returns the value of column G just fine.  If I set the index to 2, it gives me an out of bounds error.  I also want it to show all results, not just the first one.  So if there are multiple results that match, I want all of the results to show in a row separately.

EDIT:

Here is an example sheet for the formula work:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13R5VEv3cyZ3vJgb2S90xDxvpXyVV38yZXO8zIAd9OR4/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the example sheet for the external source data:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13P-nNONZuesnmByZCp6-zmIyMVJpm__nvsz3w-ItwtQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure why you need `VLOOKUP` tho...

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("13P-nNONZuesnmByZCp6-zmIyMVJpm__nvsz3w-ItwtQ", "Sheet1!A2:E"), 
 "select Col1,Col2 where Col4 = 'Engineer'")
```

[image: 0]